# Using Stored Procedure with Entity Framework where SP Parameters don't match entity

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have stored procedures that take a user's username (to log who makes changes to the database) in addition to other information (like name, ID, email, etc.).  Within the stored procedure I look up the user's ID and store that in the table.

The issue I am experiencing is that the Entity Table does not match the input of the stored procedure, therefore there is no way to map (or include) the user's username.

Is there a standard way to include non-entity properties in a stored procedure mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your question correctly (not entirely sure I do), then:

1. If you aren't already using your own DataContext derived class, do so.
2. Add a method that calls ExecuteMethodCall in that class (it's protected, so you can only call it from a derived type, passing in "raw" types (the relevant strings, ints, datetimes, etc. rather than instances of entity classes).
3. Add a method (presumably to your entity class, though it could live elsewhere) that does the necessary work for obtaining the username (whether it's a member of your class or input from elsewhere etc. isn't clear in your question) and calls the method on your DataContext-derived class.

Hope that's useful, and I'm not mis-reading.

Answer (score 0):

I created an XSLT stylesheet to generate C# methods from mapped Function Imports in the edmx. [This solution](http://devio.wordpress.com/2010/07/07/executing-stored-procedures-using-entity-framework/) works with VS2008.

Comment: I'm not working with Function Imports, I'm trying to work with the "Mapping Details" specifically "Functions".